# Show 'This page not translated' if translation doesn't exist. WP and WPML

Tags: wordpress, redirect, translation, wpml

Well, I have a WordPress site with WPML. Not all of my pages are translated to EN version. And I know to realize following. When somebody tries to go to URL which doesn't exist I want to show him/her 'Not translated page' (with a recommendation to observe this content in another language). 
How can I realize it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action('wp_head', 'wpml_custom');
function wpml_custom() {
    global $wp_query;
    $postId = $wp_query->post->ID;
    $postType = $wp_query->post->post_type;
    $args = [
        'element_id' => $postId, 'element_type' => $postType
    ];
    $translation = apply_filters( 'wpml_element_language_details', null, $args );
    $currentLang = apply_filters( 'wpml_current_language', null );

    if (preg_match('/^\/$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        return;
    } elseif ($translation->language_code !== $currentLang) {
        require get_template_directory()  . '/no-translation.php';
        exit();
    }
```

}